# change value from one spinner2 depending on spinner1 android

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have 2 custom adapters for 2 spinners with default start values. 
I want to change the array on spinner2 from starting data2 to data3 etc.. depending on value of spinner1.

```
public class SpinerKlasa extends Activity {
String[] data1 = { "V", "A", "K", "M", "T","R", "X", "C" };
String[] data2 = { "   750", "900", "1100","1300", "1500", "1700","1950", "2250", "2700"};
String[] data3 = { "   63", "73", "103","143", "163", "203","233", "253", "293"};
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner1.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner_rows, data1));
    Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    spinner2.setAdapter(new MyAdapter2(this, R.layout.spinner_rows, data2));

                spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos,
                long arg3) {
            if (pos == 1) {

    //Here to change the array for spinner2 from data2 to data3
            }                           
        }

    });
}
```

}

My adapters are inside the SpinerKlasa.
Here is the kode:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
    String[] objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {

        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);

    }
    public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_rows, parent, false);
        TextView label = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        label.setText(data1[position]);
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        icon.setImageResource(images[position]);

        return row;
    }
}

    //here I have the **MyAdapter2** class for spinner2 almost the same as MyAdapter class
```